# How to properly build a tensor array dataset from a series of single values - tensorflow newbie

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm new to tensorflow and the dataset APIs. looks like I'm not feeding the correct lists of dicts to the tensorflow. I get the following output:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: In[0] is not a matrix. Instead it has shape [] [Op:MatMul]
```

My code is:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset( 
  "train.csv",
  [tf.float32,
   tf.int32] )

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
   tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(1,)),  #     input shape required
   tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu),
   tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile( optimizer,
           loss='categorical_crossentropy',
           metrics=['accuracy'] )

model.fit( train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator(), 
       steps_per_epoch = 1,
       verbose = 2 )
```

Would expect the model top start training.....

Comment: What is the shape of your dataset?

Comment: CSV file contains only one feature (float32). The labels are 0 or 1. There are 100 training examples.

Comment: Here's a printout: train_dataset is <CsvDataset shapes: ((), ()), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>
features is: tf.Tensor(0.39382437, shape=(), dtype=float32)
labels is: tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int32)

Comment: So, when you print `dataframe.shape` do you get something like: `(100, )` ?

Comment: do you mean `tf.shape(train_dataset)` by `dataframe.shape`?

Comment: No, let's forget about TensorFlow for a moment, and look at the raw data table. What is its shape? You can check it with `dataframe.shape`

Comment: apologies, I don't know what `dataframe.shape` is... I have no variable by that name

Comment: The data that you are using for your model must be stored in some object, right? Probably a pandas dataframe, or a numpy array... whatever that `dataframe` object is, can you print the result of `dataframe.shape`?

Comment: No, the data is coming from a CSV file. It is being read by CsvDataset class as follows: `train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset( 
  "train.csv",
  [tf.float32,
   tf.int32] )`

Comment: CSV file contains 100 rows and two columns.

Answer (score 0):

I have few observations:

1)  As far as I understood, the problem is with the format of the data you fill in.
In the comments you said that your CSV file has a (100, 2) shape.
However, you have specified a 10 nodes input layer. So, your neural network is expecting to receive 10 variables as input, but you only feed 2 (because you only have 2 columns). This is going to return error for sure. The next problem is that it's very difficult (not to say impossible) tu implement a newural network with such a small input. If you're trying to learn, I'd suggest you to start with another dataset. The internet is full of cool datasets that are thought specifically for learning the bases of ML.

2) If you are using keras, then you don't need plain TensorFlow function (such as `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer`). You can train models just with Keras functions (which has a different syntax). You can group a lot of instructions using `model.compile`. I suggest you to take a look at the [Keras Guide to Sequential models](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/).

3) I strongly suggest you to import data using `pandas` library. You can do that with:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv("path/to/dataframe.csv")
```

And then you convert it into a matrix with:

```
dataframe = dataframe.values
```

This turns it into a numpy array, which works perfectly for pretty much any deep learning library.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it.